# When is it ok to instantiate all of my objects upfront?

Tags: object-oriented, programming-practices, ruby

I am currently working with a contractor who's code instantiates a large number of objects upfront at the start of the application.  This application is written in ruby, but I wonder how something like this is viewed in programming in general.

So, are there any cases where instantiating a large number of objects upfront is acceptable? Or is it generally more common to instantiate objects as you need them?

Comment: It is going to depend significantly on what kind of objects we're talking about, whats involved in instantiating them, and what kind of application the software is used for.

Comment: Is your contractor using Dependency Injection?

Comment: Both fair questions. To give a little more context, it is a page object framework used in web application automation. At the start of each test run (regardless of which tests are going to be executed), he instantiates all of the page objects defined in the framework (regardless of whether or not they are used by the tests) and stores them in a collection. He uses a method to then search that collection for the page object the code specifies, and then returns it if it is found.  There are no specific constructors other than the ruby built in constructor (he's not setting any properties).

Comment: Any speed or memory problems?  Sounds like he's caching his objects, in which case you might actually see some performance improvement if the objects are being used several times.

Comment: One benefit of allocating everything up front is you know whether you're going to run out of memory *before* the user starts to use your program. If you know you're going to fail, it's better to fail immediately rather than in the middle of some critical operation.

Comment: Speed and memory are going to be an issue as we are going back and forth about what type of parallel solution we want to use for executing the tests in parallel.  We also have differing opinions there as well.

Comment: It could be an issue with performance and memory, though it could equally be that he was sick of having issues with tests trying to access an object that wasn't created yet and just decided feck it I'll create all my objects up front. I've see this before, and generally it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine if it doesn't hog to many resources.  Best way to know if it does is to do it and see what happens.  This is a performance issue.  Don't fix it until you see it.

The number one reason not to allocate space upfront, objects in this case, is when you don't already know how much to allocate.  This is why heap collections are prefered over arrays. They let you allocate just what you need when you need it.

However, when you know ahead of time how much space is needed it's reasonable to hold space even when it's not being used.  Why? Because fixed memory allocations don't [leak](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=memory%20leaks%20in%20ruby).

Whenever you plan to dispose of objects, you plan to recover their memory.  If you plan for that, but don't actually do it, you end up needing a reboot.  This little annoyance is what makes all the difference between server quality software and not server quality software.  No one likes [servers that need rebooting](http://www.xkcd.com/1495/).

Now sure, if you're very careful you can dynamically allocate and deallocate and expect to get the memory back for other uses.  But being careful costs time, money, and expertise.

So, if you don't NEED to dynamically allocate, why would you?

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit like global variables (bad, bad). Or a bunch of singletons, utility objects (bad, bad). But then modules are again considered fine. Normally one would have a hierarchical structure: application - dialogs x documents.

"As you need them" is the most efficient way in general, so I would keep with that.

However there might be modular interdepencies that require a sequence of loading. This unsafe handling of dependencies means that structural code is missing for just that.

In general starting with a legacy project it is better not to start redesigning all. Be critical as you evidently are, but try to guarantee business logic.
Solve things first.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I do quite often. But my objects are lazy, there is no work carried out in constructors. Very often it's an indication of [pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) in action, which is a good thing I believe. It exhibits that domain was decomposed in highly [composable manner](https://medium.com/@wrong.about/on-good-domain-decomposition-385ee8ce5a3) and that abstractions found are highly reusable, since there is a small amount of interfaces and big amount of concrete classes implementing them. For instance, that's how my composition root could look like:

```
try {
    (new WebFront(
        new Fallback(
            new RouteChain(
                [
                    new Route(
                        new Fixed('/registration'),
                        new RegisterUserCoordinator(
                            new PostgresUserDataStorage(RpgProdConnection::me())
                        )
                    ),
                    new Authenticated(
                        new Route(
                            new Fixed('/skill/buy'),
                            new BuySkillCoordinator(
                                new AnalystStorage(RpgProdConnection::me()),
                                new TestPayPalAccount(
                                    new FakeHttpProtocol()
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        new PostgresUserDataStorage(RpgProdConnection::me())
                    )
                ]
            ),
            new UrlNotFoundResponse()
        )
    ))
        ->act(
            new HttpRequest(
                new HttpMethod($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']),
                new URL("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"),
                getallheaders(),
                new Data($_POST)
            )
        )
    ;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(['code' => 666, 'message' => 'System failure. Come back later.']);
}
```